# Create our own property page for project explorer eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a custom project in project explorer. I have various folders in the project explorer and also images in one of the folder. I want to create my own property page and want to customize the same on clicking any resource in the project explorer. I have gone through all possible articles on web but not able to solve the problem. Can anyone please help me or provide me some code to create my own property page. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can contribute a workbench property page by following [this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_resources.htm).

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html) seems to have a nice overview on creating a tabbed properties page. Is this something that you are looking for?

Comment: This is different than the properties page when you select the project and do right-click `Properties` and it gives you the properties dialog, which is I think what he wants. What the tabbed properties are about is the properties *view* which is different.

Comment: Yes, then your answer would be the one he wants