# Eclipse Nature-specific Project Properties

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse plugin with a custom project nature. The nature itself works fine. I need to implement a project-specific properties page that allows the user to customize settings specific to that nature; thus far, I have been unsuccessful and would apppreciate any help. I envision this to be similar to how the Java nature allows one to set project-specific compiler options, formatter settings, etc.

It is crucial that the project settings are stored in the project itself, similar to how Java settings are stored in `(project root)/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.*.prefs`. These need to be in source control for that project so the whole team is beholden to the same standards.

Here is what I have so far in the plugin.xml:

```
  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page id="test.MyOverlayPage"
          name="%Key.PropertyPage"
          class="test.MyOverlayPage">
      <enabledWhen>
        <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
      </enabledWhen>
    </page>
  </extension>
```

This obviously does not restrict the property page by nature the way the Java settings are, but currently this does not show up for *any* project, let alone ones with the custom nature.

I found the following questions which do not address my specific concern:

[Create our own property page for project explorer eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953179/create-our-own-property-page-for-project-explorer-eclipse-plugin)

[Eclipse: Storing info in .project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525213/eclipse-storing-info-in-project-file)

I also found this Eclipse help page which is severely lacking in details and I have not been able to get this working based on it:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_properties.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java property pages use this:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
              value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
    </adapt>         
</enabledWhen>
```

This uses `adapt` instead of `instanceof` because UI objects in a view are often not instances of projects (or other resources). Instead they use the `IAdapterManager` to convert (adapt) from the UI class to the workspace model class.

The `test` element adds a test on the project nature, here it is for the Java nature id but you can substitute your nature id.

To save preferences in the project `.settings` use something like:

```java
IProject project =  ... get project from selection or something

IScopeContext context = new ProjectScope(project);

Preferences projectPreferences = context.getNode("your nature id");

projectPreferences.put(key, value);

projectPreferences.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Looks like I was closer than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If your page is extension of org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyPage you can get project via:

```
private IProject getProject() {
   final IAdaptable adaptable = getElement();
   return adaptable == null ? null : (IProject) adaptable.getAdapter(IProject.class);
}
```