# Eclipse PDE :: The use of adapt in filter expressions

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin

In `plugin.xml` of the plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` I found the following `commonFilter` element definition:

```
      <commonFilter
        id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot"
        name="%filters.startsWithDot.name"
        description="%filters.startsWithDot.description"
        activeByDefault="true"
        >
     <filterExpression>
        <and>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value=".*"/>
            </adapt>
        </and>
     </filterExpression>
  </commonFilter>
```

It's the usage of `adapt` that troubles me:

1. How come the element `and` can be used as a *unary* operator on its (only) subelement? From my understanding the AND operator needs *two* operands.
2. Inspired by the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21269813/5052877), I looked into the Javadoc of `IAdapterManager` and came to the conclusion that the usage of `adapt` translates to something like

   ```
   Platform.getAdapterManager().registerAdapters(pr, IResource.class);
   ```

   somewhere in the Eclipse source where `pr` is the instance of an adapter factory. Is that correct?
3. What is `adapt` technically? Simply an XML element? (I'm asking because I suspect more Eclipse PDE terminology here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<and>` can have any number of child elements. The result is the 'and' of the results of all the children. So one element is OK, but it doesn't really do anything.

`<adapt>` is just a normal XML element and isn't treated specially. It is used here because most UI objects are not actually files or folders. `<adapt>` uses the adapter interface to 'adapt' to the 'type' specified (if possible). The child elements of 'adapt' are then given the adapted type. The value returned by 'adapt' is the 'and' of its children.

So in this case the `<test>` element is given the `IResource` object to test rather than the original UI object.

`<adapt>` will use the `getAdapter` method of the `IAdapterManager` returned by `Platform.getAdapterManager()` to do the adapt. It may also check if the current class implements `IAdaptable`.

`IAdapterManager.registerAdapters` is used by classes that want to provide adapters to register an `IAdapterFactory` that the adapter manager can consult when `getAdapter` is called.

Comment: Thanks again, Greg! Is it correct that `adapt` translates to a call to `registerAdapters()`?

Comment: No it uses `IAdapterManager.getAdapter` to look for an already registered adapter. It may also check if the current class implements `IAdaptable`.  `registerAdapters` is usually called during Eclipse startup by various plugins to tell the adapter manager about adapter factories.